# how to migrate from TFS to GIT with history?

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I'm following the standard approach that everyone is doing on the internet.
I've installed chocolatey and git-tf.
I've used the powershell command

`git tf clone https://your-server/tfs/collection $/Project/Path local-dir`

and for some reason it's showing that it's connecting but then it stops with the below error message:
**git-tf: The server's response does not seem to be a SOAP message**.
I cant find any thread on the internet addressing this problem, would be nice if someone could help ?

**UPDATE: while using git-tf, the error message is "git-tf: The server's response does not seem to be a SOAP message."
while using git tfs, the error message is "Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
HTTP code 200: OK"**

Thanks

Comment: you talked about 2 tools that try to achive that `git-tf` and `git-tfs`. Please correct the question so that we really know which one you used...

Comment: What version of TFS?

Comment: TFS version 2010

Comment: Use git-tfs. Git-tf is no longer maintained and is an all-around inferior tool.

Comment: @DanielMann `git-tf` is perhap an inferior tool but it could be useful in some specific use cases. And, to be frank, nowadays, `git-tfs` is not a lot more maintained (I know, I am the maintainer)...